# Rewrite query string apache

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite my url as the following:

```
http://test.com/listing?p=2
```

to

```
http://test.com/listing/p/2
```

Any solutions, please kindly to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^listing/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ /listing/?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Apache url rewriting is something I keep putting it off. Sooner or later I have to learn this. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I'm not the OP, I'm just looking at your answer. =P

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida: My apologies :)

Comment: What doesn't work? If you want help at least provide enough information of the error. What URL are you entering in your browser and what is location of this .htaccess file?